# loading php script inside html page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to load a page on select on change event. But it aint displaying the page. the content on the page is just: this is bank/ this is cash.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<select id = "ddl" onchange="changeSheet()">
<option value = "bank">Bank Statement</option>
<option value = "cash">Cash Book</option>
</select>

<div id = "sheet">
</div>

<script>
function changeSheet()
{
    document.getElementById('sheet').innerHTML = "";
    var e = document.getElementById("ddl");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if(strUser == 'bank')
    {
        $("#sheet").load("bank.php");
    }
    else 
    {
        $("#sheet").load("cash.php");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have to look into ajax calls

Comment: If you're using firefox with firebug plugin and press F12 you should see the console. xhr request show up in console including their content. Do you have any errors in there loading the php or in your javascript? Chrome has a console too and opens with F12 as well.

Comment: Not sure if this is your actual markup, but you may also be receiving errors for using what appear to be jQuery selectors without including the jQuery library.

Comment: Tip: try to attach your script to dom elements in javascript, do not use on... in your html code. In jquery this is as simple as `$('#ddl').on('load',null,null,myfunciton);`

Comment: Where are you loading jQuery at? I don't see any included js files as the header is empty. So using .load() will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do that using JQuery: <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/130/)</kbd>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<select id = "ddl" onchange="changeSheet()">
    <option value = "bank">Bank Statement</option>
    <option value = "cash">Cash Book</option>
</select>

<div id = "sheet"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ddl").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === "bank")
            $("#sheet").load("bank.php");    
        else 
            $("#sheet").load("cash.php");   
    });
});
</script>
```